# RegEx filter links from a document

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am currently learning regex and I am trying to filter all links (eg: http://www.link.com/folder/file.html) from a document with **notepad++**. Actually I want to delete everything else so that in the end only the http links are listed.

So far I tried this : `http\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+`

This gives me all links which is find, but how do I delete the remaining stuff so that in the end I have a neat list of all links?

If I try to replace it with nothing followed by \1, obviously the link will be deleted, but I want the exact opposite to have everything else deleted.

So it should be something like:
- find a string of numbers, letters and special signs until "http"
- delete what you found 
- and keep searching for more numbers, letters ans special signs after "html" 
- and delete that again

Any ideas? Thanks so much.

Comment: What about copying the links to another file?

Comment: The best solution I was able to come up with with purely regex was to isolate each link onto its own line, though it also put the ending of strings (ex: any text after a link at the end of a line) on its own line.

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Notepad++, in the Replace menu (CTRL+H) you can do the following:

- Find: `.*?(http\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+)`
- Replace: `$1\n`
- Options: check the `Regular expression` and the `. matches newline`

This will return you with a list of all your links. There are two issues though:

1. The regex you provided for matching URLs is far from being generic enough to match any URL. If it is working in your case, that's fine, else check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/2140859).
2. It will leave the text after the last matched URL intact. You have to delete it manually.

Comment: In my case the regex for the matching urls is fine, but your .*? doesn't work for some reason. And I don't know why but the rest will only replace the url with $1...!?

Comment: Double check that 1) you actually checked the "Regular expression" radio button and 2) you have the latest version of Notepad++ which is now v6.5 (at least not lower than v6.0) and let me know.

Comment: Currently I am on a Mac using TextWrangler, can check notepad++ later. At least text wrangler just replaces the whole link except für the closing last part > of the closing tag with the $1.

Comment: Checked on Windows in notepad++ now and it works! Thanks so much. That gave me such a headache. Can someone explain in one sentence why the regex worked in notepad++ but not in an other editor?

Comment: Both of them are using the same regex engine (PCRE) so theoretically it should work on TextWrangler too. Did you check the equivalent ". matches newline" option in TextWrangler? Unfortunately I can't test it on TW.

Comment: I did but it didn't work. Pretty strange, because I was told by a friend that as long as I don't have access to a Windows PC I could use TextWrangler. Anyway thanks for help. I am still looking for a way to search for the second or thrid string of letters in a line though. Eg. ab ab ab, but only replace the second "ab" with "cd" and jump to the next line to do the same again.

Comment: 1. Since it is a different question I would suggest you to write a new question! It is an easy one, you will receive multiple answers in a few minutes! 2. Also when you consider a question as being answered don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer made previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19718805/4094098) by @psxls was a great help for me when I have wanted to perform a similar process.

However, this `regex` rule was written six years ago now: accordingly, I had to *adjust / complete / update* it in order it can properly work with the some recent links, because:

1. a lot of URL are now using `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP` protocol
2. many websites less use `www` as main subdomain
3. some links adds punctuation mark (which have to be preserved)

I finally reshuffle the search rule to `.*?(https?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9[:punct:]]+)` and it worked correctly with the file I had.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer won't be RegEx related, but here is another efficient way to get lines containing URLs.
This won't remove text around links like Toto mentioned in comments.

At least if there is nice pattern to all links, like `https://`.

1. CTRL+F => change tab to `Mark`
2. Insert `https://`
3. Tick `Mark to bookmark`.
4. `Mark All`.
5. `Find` => `Bookmarks` => `Delete all lines without bookmark`.

I hope someone who lands here in search of same problem will find my way more user-friendly.

You can still use RegEx to mark lines :)

Comment: This will not remove text around links as wanted.

Comment: @Toto for this situation I would recommend any online "link extractor". [Browseling](https://www.browserling.com/tools/extract-urls) - like this one, but adding another tool to solution is not always welcomed solution. But if it works, it is a solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this seemingly simple task is going to be almost impossible to do in notepad++.  The regex you would have to construct would be...horrible.  It might not even be possible, but if it is, it's not worth it.  I pretty much guarantee that.

However, all is not lost.  There are other tools more suitable to this problem.

Really what you want is a tool that can search through an input file and print out a list of regex matches.  The UNIX utility "grep" will do just that.  Don't be scared off because it's a UNIX utility: you can get it for Windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

The grep command line you'll want to use is this:

```
grep -o 'http:\/\/www.[a-zA-Z0-9./-]\+\?' <filename(s)>
```

(Where `<filename(s)>` are the name(s) of the files you want to search for URLs in.)

You might want to shake up your regex a little bit, too.  The problems I see with that regex are that it doesn't handle URLs without the 'www' subdomain, and it won't handle secure links (which start with `https`).  Maybe that's what you want, but if not, I would modify it thusly:

```
grep -o 'https\?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9./-]\+\?' <filename(s)>
```

Here are some things to note about these expressions:

1. Inside a character group, there's no need to quote metacharacters except for `[` and (sometimes) `-`.  I say sometimes because if you put the dash at the end, as I have above, it's no longer interpreted as a range operator.
2. The grep utility's syntax, annoyingly, is different than most regex implementations in that most of the metacharacters we're familiar with (`?`, `+`, etc.) must be *escaped* to be used, not the other way around.  Which is why you see backslashes before the `?` and `+` characters above.
3. Lastly, the repetition metacharacter in this expression (`+`) is greedy by default, which could cause problems.  I made it lazy by appending a `?` to it.  The way you have your URL match formulated, it probably wouldn't have caused problems, but if you change your match to, say `[^ ]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9./-]`, you would see URLs on the same line getting combined together.

Comment: What if I switch over to a Mac. I know that Textwrangler should be using grep, right? Still would it be the same command?

Comment: Yes, this command will be available in the console on most Macs without you having to install anything at all.

Comment: But I still don't get how to delete everything except for the links?

Comment: Well, that won't delete everything except for links exactly: it will output ONLY the links, which accomplishes the same thing.  Just redirect this to a file (end the command with ` > output.txt`) and you'll have a text file with just the links in it.

Comment: If you're trying to transform an HTML document, that's slightly different...but this would still be a good place to start.

Comment: If I stick with textwrangler or notepad... 1. how could I search with regex on a line until it finds "http" - in that case I could just replace everything up to the http with "nothing". And 2. afterwards start to search again after the html until it finds the next http.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a different way.
Find everything up to the first/next (https or http) (then everything that comes next) up to (html or htm), then output just the '(https or http)(everything next) then (html or htm)' with a line feed/ carriage return after each.

So:
Find: `.*?(https:|http:)(.*?)(html|htm)`
Replace with: `\1\2\3\r\n`

Saves looking for all possible (incl non-generic) url matches.

You will need to manually remove any text after the last matched URL.

Can also be used to create url links:
Find: `.*?(https:|http:)(.*?)(html|htm)`
Replace: `<a href="\1\2\3">\1\2\3</a>\r\n`

or image links (jpg/jpeg/gif):
Find: `.*?(https:|http:)(.*?)(jpeg|jpg|gif)`
Replace: `<img src="\1\2\3">\r\n`

Comment: Why using 3 capture groups when only one is enough? `\1` notation for replacement is very old syntax, it's better to use `$1`, `\1` is used for backreference in the regex. `(https:|http:)` is better writen `(https?:)` same for `(html|htm)` --> `(html?)`

Comment: You're right, thanks. It was a long time ago when I was looking at this.

Find: .*?(https?:.*?html?)
Replace: $1\r\n